# Delay sleep/login page when closing laptop lid on Windows?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, sleep, power-management, lid

I want to be able to close my laptop lid, but not have the laptop got to sleep for a set amount of time (e.g. 5 minutes). If I open the laptop in that time, it bring be back to where I was without a login screen. If the time limit expires, the laptop should sleep, then present a login page when awakened. Is there any way to do this in Windows 8.1? I've explored the power options to no avail, and I can't find an event in the event viewer that I could use to trigger a scheduled task.

The Lenovo power manager had such an option a few years ago for some laptops, but they seem to have discontinued it since laptops got faster to resume from sleep, but my main concern here is that I don't want a login screen quite so frequently - similar to my phone, which has a certain timeout before the lock screen is enabled.

Comment: Perhaps set "sleep after 5 minutes idle" setting on your power option? And "on close of lid" - do nothing. So the laptop will stay on, and after 5 minutes of idle it will sleep?

Comment: @Darius - I've been trying that for a while, but the main problem is it won't wake up automatically when I open it. Also, I generally prefer a longer time before going to sleep than 5 minutes.