# Delaying Sleep Mode When Closing Lid on Windows 10 on ThinkPad T460

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management

I am running Windows 10 (build 19045) on a ThinkPad T460 and I am looking for a way to delay sleep when the lid is closed.

I want to be able to set a 15 to 60 second delay after I close the lid of the laptop to put it to sleep.

There was a similar [post](https://superuser.com/questions/894013/delay-sleep-login-page-when-closing-laptop-lid-on-windows) from 7 years ago but it still remains un-answered.

I'm open to installing 3rd party programs to get this functionality since it seems to be missing from Windows as a feature. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is most likely BIOS functionality. That is probably why the post remains unanswered.

Comment: My understanding was that Windows triggered the sleep function, since you're able to disable sleep when closing the lid altogether through control center?

Comment: That is integrated with and under the control of BIOS on ThinkPads.  That is my experience with them.

Comment: Did you try third-party utilities that help you delay sleep when the lid is closed, such as Caffeine, KeepAwake, etc.?

Comment: Could you provide a link to those programs?

Comment: After looking into both these programs it doesn't look like that either of these programs accomplish what i'm looking for. Main goal is to get the computer to sleep after 15 seconds from the moment the lid is closed of which neither of those accomplish.